# Lint gives "Wrong format type" when using long values in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, lint

My project uses a string declaration in strings.xml similar to:

```
<string name="file_size">File Size (%1$dMB)</string>
```

And in my code, I'm using

```
getResources().getString(R.string.file_size, getFileSize());
```

Where getFileSize() returns a long.  Lint give me this error:

"Wrong argument type for formatting argument '#1' in file_size: conversion is 'd', received long (argument #2 in method call)"

What's going on here?  The Android documentation says that:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the lint rules. See the source for [`StringFormatDetector`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/StringFormatDetector.java):

```
// Numeric: integer and floats in various formats
case 'x':
case 'X':
case 'd':
case 'o':
case 'e':
case 'E':
case 'f':
case 'g':
case 'G':
case 'a':
case 'A':
    valid = type == Integer.TYPE
            || type == Float.TYPE;
    break;
```